# Help me with an algebra question

Tags: word-problem

I am trying to solve this question

> Example: Alex and Sam also build tables. Together they make 10 tables
> in 12 days.
>
> Alex working alone can make 10 in 30 days.
>
> How long would it take Sam working alone to make 10 tables?

[From this site](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/word-questions-solving.html)

I calculated how many tables Alex can do in 1 day by doing 30/10 = 3.

I then did 12/3 = 4 to calculate how many Alex did in 12 days.

To find out how many tables Sam did in 12 days I did 12-4 = 8.

Now I can work out Sam's daily work rate by doing 12/8 = 1.5

If I do 1.5 * 10 then Sam will take 15 days to do 10 tables.

The website came to a different conclusion: `So 10 tables would take Sam just 20 days.`

Where has my logic gone astray?

Comment: Have another look at your first line, the numer of table Alex can do in a day.  If he can do 10 tables in 30 days, can he really do 3 tables in 1 day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex can do one table every three days. In the twelve days they are with Sam, they do $12/3=4$ tables. Together they all made $10$ tables, so Sam must have made the remaining $6$ tables in $12$ days, so their work rate is one table every two days. The website concludes correctly; $10$ tables times $2$ days equals $20$ days taken to make the $10$ tables.